# LED bulb wattage query

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver

I was trying to check the wattage of an LED bulb. How to know manufacturer's spec is correct?

Comment: You do measurements

Answer (score 3):

*How to know manufacturer's spec is correct?*

You confirm it by **measurement**.

[Big Clive on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmJDv5CqaGU) often looks at LED lightbulbs and he uses a [HOPI meter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/HOPI-HP-9800-Handheld-Power-Meter-Power-Analyzer-LED-Metering-Socket-Measurable-Current-voltage-Power-Factor/32375959317.html) for measurements.

[image]

You could also use a cheaper equivalent like this one:

[image]

But it will probably be unable to accurately measure the 1 W of your bulb.

But what are you hoping to gain by knowing if a LED bulb meets its specification? It either emits enough light or it does not. If it is a bad design it will get warm and probably not last long. For me amount of light and heat output (and related to that: lifetime) are more important in a LED light bulb then a specification on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multimeter to measure the forward voltage of the LED. Then measure the current being drawn by the LED.

You can calculate Wattage by using: `W = A x V`

It should generally be close to what the manufacturer specifications are if you are providing it a typical voltage.

Comment: Assuming that these are ac measurements, what you have found is the **apparent power** with units of VA, not real power with units of watts. But, as you suggest, if the power factor is close to 1 then the apparent power should be only a little more than the real power.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: depends on the multimeter that you have and the waveform that is driving the LEDs

Comment: This answer applies to a LED (or some LEDs) running on a DC voltage. For a light bulb running on AC, things are more complicated.

Comment: I didn't realize OP was referring to a mains power LED Bulb. My answer only pertains to DC LED Components.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm not talking about rms vs. avg. vs peak voltage and current, or about sinusoids vs. other waveforms. If you measure current and voltage **separately** then multiply you get apparent power. To get real power you must multiply instantaneous voltage times instantaneous current. The difference is, essentially, the power factor of the load. A significant difference arises if the current and voltage are not in phase or if the shape of their waveforms is different.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: some multimeters can measure power directly. For some waveforms its fine to measure truerms voltage and current to get a reasonable wattage. For some LED bulbs the voltage (and thus current) waveform is reasonably near enough to DC to ignore the waveform.